# Using Apigee as auth store alternative to Auth0

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0, apigee, google-cloud-platform

**Background**

I'm looking into securing a selection of APIs for a client. I'm pretty familiar with the [Auth0](https://auth0.com) offering and quite confident that it will serve me well as an auth provider.

The APIs will be deployed on GCP (Google Cloud Platform) and I've been looking into using [Apigee](http://apigee.com) to manage the life cycle of my APIs.

**Question**

Does [Apigee](http://apigee.com) offer an auth store for users similar to what [Auth0](https://auth0.com) offers or is [Apigee](http://apigee.com)'s OAuth implementation limited to application level authentication using Consumer Key and Consumer Secret as described [here](https://docs.apigee.com/tutorials/secure-calls-your-api-through-oauth-20-client-credentials)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apigee OAuth implementation is not limited to Consumer Key/Secret (client credentials grant) but you also can implement different OAuth grant types. Apigee can generate/validate JWT and it's own opaque tokens.

The problem is that Apigee does not provide Identity Provider (IdP) service, it means that it does not have a store for user credentials. You may utilize Apigee's BaaS (Backend-as-a-Service) to store users or integrate Apigee with other IdPs, but there's no built-in solution to authenticate users.